# Why does my content spill over the table size?

Tags: html, css

Background - i've got an excel doc that i'm turning into a html doc and it has 69rows and 82columns but iv come across two problems.

1. My a3 form is spilling over the dimensions of the a3 printing size.
2. The content in my form starts spilling over each other when trying to convert my a3 form to an a4. Is there a calculation that you can do to stop this?

Please can someone help?

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 7px;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#tblContainer {
    width: 1191px;
    height: 842px;
    outline: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

#table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;  

}

#table td {
    /* outline: 1px solid black; */
    height: 12.20px;
    min-height: 12.20px;
    max-height: 12.20px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="top-border right-border left-border">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="right-border"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="right-border"></td>
    <td class="bottom-border" colspan="14" rowspan="3"><img class="logo" src="" alt="Ambulance">
        <!-- Logo -->
    </td>
    <td class="blueColour left-border" colspan="9"><b>Cardiac Arrest</b></td>
    <td class="blueColour" colspan="6">Arrest Witnessed by:</td>
    <td class="blueColour right-border" colspan="6"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2">Manual</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>OP</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2">Nasal</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: could you please be more clear with ur question and what ur trying to do

Comment: So iv got an excel sheet that i'm creating into a static html form. The excel sheet has 69 rows and 82 columns with data in. Iv created a html form using the dimensions above and the calculation height: 842px / 69rows = 12.20 px per TD. However, the content spills over the dimension of the A3. The second problem is that i'm trying to convert to a4 as i only have an a4 printer. The issue i get when i convert to a4 is that the content get muddled up.

Comment: oohhh, i dont know the answer to this one

Comment: We tried to make your code a runnable snippet. Won't represent what you are trying to do correctly, though. I would say don't give a fixed width like this: `width: 1191px;`. Make a print CSS which works with `mm` or `in` to match your page exactly.

Comment: @PeterKrebs - Iv done that already but didnt work :/

Comment: Well sure, then please list what you have tried. Scaling the print before printing is not a desirable option, I assume?